# How to find and group records which have same conditions subsequently?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection

We have a table which we record our students' attendances in. We need to find out which students missed n number of contacts in a row.

Here is the attendance table structure with example records

```
----------------------------------------------------
| id  | student_id |  class_id  |  checkedin_time  | 
--------------------------------------------------
| 1   |      1     |     1      |       null       |
| 2   |      1     |     2      | 2019-07-09 10:30 |
| 3   |      1     |     3      |       null       |
| 4   |      1     |     4      |       null       |
| 5   |      1     |     5      | 2019-07-12 12:00 |
----------------------------------------------------
```

What I'm looking for is a code that show me records with id 3 and 4 (two subsequent missed contacts) grouped by student_id

This was my starting point:

```
$attendances = \App\Attendance::where('checked_time' , null)->get();
$attendances->groupBy('student_id')
```

Comment: You want to call `groupBy()` before `get()`.

Comment: @HeySora this still show all of attendances which where missed, not subsequent ones,

Comment: Yes, I was just pointing out the error before going further!

Comment: @HeySora It's not an error. `get()` method returns a __Laravel Collection__ which has a method called `groupBy()`.

Comment: @TharakaDilshan Oh, my bad! I have the habit of doing everything before `get()` so the `groupBy()` just makes a `GROUP BY` in SQL, instead of filtering the collection afterwards.